# Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe looks like this

```
   survived pclass  sex age sibsp   parch   fare    embarked
    0   1   1   female  29.0000 0   0   211.3375    S
    1   1   1   male    0.9167  1   2   151.5500    S
    2   0   1   female  2.0000  1   2   151.5500    S
    3   0   1   male    30.0000 1   2   151.5500    S
    4   0   1   female  25.0000 1   2   151.5500    S
```

I want to convert 'sex' to 0, 1 coding and used isnull checked that there is no NA in the column

However, on this line I received ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

```
df['sex'] = df['sex'].map({'female':0, 'male':1}).astype(int)
```

Any suggestions ? thank you !

Comment: No, if want integer with NaNs values it is problem, check dupe. Possible solution is remove all NaNs rows by column `Sex` or replace `NaN` to some integer like `fillna(2).astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.where`

**Ex:**

```
import numpy as np

df['sex'] = np.where(df['sex'] == 'female', 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to do it is by using the [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function

```
df.replace({'sex':{'female':0, 'male':1}}, inplace=True)
```

If your df has nans, then you could fill them by some value, e.g. -1, using [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then replace the rest

```
df.fillna({'sex':-1}, inplace=True)
df.replace({'sex':{'female':0, 'male':1}}, inplace=True)
```